# jQuery isn't working on FF, but works on Chrome

Tags: jquery, firefox

[Guys check this website on FF and Chrome](http://foxklld.site88.net/)
For some reason(s), jQuery isn't working on FF, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're running into issues with how Firefox and Chrome render the CSS3 flexible box model.

Change the css definition of "#nav ul" to use "#nav ul **li**" instead.

This should work in firefox now.
But then it breaks in chrome... but if you add "float:left" to "#nav ul li" then it should work in both browsers.

Comment: Is going to be fixed in both browsers in near future?

Comment: that's always hard to say. Especially now that it seems the W3C is moving towards a "grid" model and dropping the flexible box model.

Comment: Thnx for replaying! And I want to ask do you know good sources where I can learn about grib model? Because I new to web and used most of the time HTML5 to create websites. Also, I heard about http://960.gs but have no idea how to use it.

Comment: I am getting the same issue. Here are the details - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25461774/how-to-fix-nav-bar-position-and-fix-compatibility-issue-in-firefox .  How may I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Only thing I see is this  http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Ffoxklld.site88.net%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

doesn't seem to like the analytics code existing outside of the body.  Also firefox throws this error "XUL box for body element contained an inline #text child, forcing all its children to be wrapped in a block." which means it thinks you are running XUL somewhere.  Try putting those scripts in the body and see what happens.