# How to fix nav-bar position?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is my [Personal Webpage](http://www.personalwebpage123456789.com). Try both Chrome and Firefox. The intended effect is rendered only on firefox (only for the homepage portion). 
However when I scroll down and scroll back up to the homepage,the image disappears. **Why is this happening and how may I solve this?**
Also,How can I render the homepage parallax scrolling effect in Chrome? 

Related Code:
**HTML:**

```
<section class="featured">
            <div class="container"> 

                <div class="row mar-bot40">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

                        <div class="align-center">
                            <div class="team-member">
                                <figure class="member-photo1" ><img class="works" src="img/Work/me.jpg"  alt="" /></figure>

                        </div>
                            <h2 class="slogan" style="color:white;">name<a style="color:white;font-family: 'Lobster', cursive; font-weight:normal">.com</a></h2><h3 style="font-family: 'Shadows Into Light', cursive; color:#A2F1FE; font-size:35px;"><strong>Inspired by <a style="color:#FF2744">Purpose</a>.<br>Driven by <a style="color:#FF2744">Passion</a>.</strong></h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                            <div class="row animated opacity mar-bot20" data-andown="fadeIn" data-animation="animation">
                <div class="col-sm-12 align-center">
                    <ul class="social-network social-circle">
            <li><a href="mailto:name@gmail.com" target="_top" class="icoGmail" title="Gmail"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://github.com/" class="icoGit" title="Github"><i class="fa fa-github"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" class="icoFacebook" title="Facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank" class="icoTwitter" title="Twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://plus.google.com/+" class="icoGoogle" title="Google +"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/users/2477978/"  class="icoStackoverflow" title="Stackoverflow"><i class="fa fa-stack-overflow"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/pub/-ganguly/52/641/301" class="icoLinkedin" title="LinkedIn"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                    </ul>   
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>

        </section>
```

**CSS:**

```
section.featured {
    padding: 200px 0 255px;
    background: url('homepage.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    color: #fdfdfd;

}

section.featured h2.slogan {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 48px;
    font-weight: 900;
}

 /* inner heading */
section.featured.inner {
    background: #eee;
    padding: 150px 0 50px;
}
```

Comment: Could it have something to do with your JS? Chrome Dev Tools show an error of: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null main.js:40
ml main.js:40
Sl main.js:45
init

Comment: i can't reproduce the behavior you described. whats your browser versions?

Comment: looks exactly the same in Chrome and FF for me. You've A LOT of unclosed elements, though

Comment: Solved your Parallax problem! see last edit!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#solved it!

> I have noticed very strange behavior that when image is not showing!
>
> Try to resize you browser a bit and boom! it will show you background
> image! (this might be a hint where we can focus)

Try to longhand the shorthand properties!

- I have just simplified your short-hand properties!
- then i have removed `background-attachment: fixed;` (and that was creating the problem)
- But i have just checked in inspect elements 3-times and its working!

By removing `background-attachment: fixed;` property and load page again!

just use these css:

```
section.featured {
    padding: 200px 0 255px;
    background-image: url('homepage.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    color: #fdfdfd;
}
```

---

And for the performance issue i have noticed that

- you have used so many fonts links (font-awesome twice and around 15! Thats too much)
- around 300 lines of embedded css!
- try to minify `js`,`css` and `html` and reduce http-request!
- website is very slow due to 79 http request!

---

#For Header issue!

> I have analysed your code and its overriding css rules that why your
> header is not looking as you want!

- for that i have removed some css rules!
- please remove this rules, i think that will solve your problem!

[image: css]

After removing some css header will look like this

![header][2]

#For the header Links

- Firts of all remove all inline styles for links

[image: remove]

Now add this css to your stylesheet!

```
.navbar .nav>li>a {
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif !important;
padding: 10px 15px 10px;
color: #fff !important;
}

.navbar .nav>li>a:hover {
color: #ccc !important;
}
```

## Active Link Code Modification!

Here is the steps for active link color background issue!
[image]

---

> For active Color Link Activation please make sure that when you click
> on linnk its `<li>` becomes `<li class="active">`, Then and only then
> it will become active red!

---

#Final Retouch! Working Parallax Effect

```
section.featured {
    padding: 200px 0 255px;
    background-image: url('homepage3.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: static;
    background-position: inherit;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -o-background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    color: #fdfdfd;
}
```

[image: final parallax]

![staaaaaaaaaaakkkkkk][6]

#Goodluck

Comment: <script type="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
 var url = window.location;
// Will also work for relative and absolute hrefs
$('.navbar .navbar-nav ul.nav a').filter(function() {
    return this.href == url;
}).parent().addClass('active');
</script>

Comment: I tried the above code to set the active element,but still not working! I saw your edit almost instantly but I thought you were gonna update it!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60299/discussion-between-eirenaios-and-kaushaya).

Comment: Happy to help! Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is off. The side effect of that is it confuses the javascript.

Think of HTML as a skeleton, it should be symmetrical, if it's asymmetrical one side will be bigger than the other which causes numerous internal problems. You wouldn't want 5 fingers on one hand and only 3 on the other.

You have **174 opening** `<div>` tags but **178 ending** tags. On top of that you have **13 opening** `<section>` tags but **15 ending** tags. I surmise that the error was made due to the commented out sections of code. I suggest using an IDE (Notepad++ or NetBeans) that points out simple mistakes (via colored underlining). Simple mistake, like a missing semi-colon, that could have been prevented.

Heed W3C standards, they're there for a reason. [**This W3C**](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.kaushayaganguly.com%2F&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) report strengthens my hypothesis; fix your HTML errors and your problem should be solved.

Comment: I fixed the opening and ending tags. Thanks for pointing it out to me. However,it still served no purpose in my endeavor to fix the nav bar. Also, I'm getting Firefox compatibility issue for the Project section.

Comment: Firefox issue fixed. The nav bar still troubling me. Also, parallax scrolling for homepage is gone!

Answer (score 0):

After investigating I believe the root of the problem lies with the way position fixed is being used on the `section featured` background image.

Position fixed is not working as per the W3C specification in Google chrome which is also why the parallax scrolling effect is failing to work in Chrome.

Simply **REMOVING FIXED** from your background position should resolve the problem of the image disappearing on scroll.

**CHANGE FROM**

```
section.featured {
    background: url('homepage.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
}
```

**TO**

```
section.featured {
    background: url('homepage.jpg') no-repeat center center; 
}
```

When the background is set as fixed, it is similar to putting a fixed 'div' in the background and setting the original div background to be transparent.

This is actually a bug in Google Chrome. 
*(Despite its popularity Chrome still does not comform to web standards as well as firefox.)*

---

### RESOLUTION

Although I have been unable to test this with your website their is a workaround for this bug.

Setting the '**position**' propery of the element AND ALL parent elements as '**static**', or if you have given it some other value, namely '**relative**', '**fixed**' or '**absolute**', just remove those.

If the element or any container element, including: `body` & `html` has any position property other than static the bug will occur.

**Additionally:**

Ensure that `backface-visibility: hidden;` is not set on the element or any of its containers, including: `body` & `html`.

---

### ALTERNATE SOLUTIONS

One alternative is to use the css clip function to create a similar effect.

## CLICK FOR DEMO


*Demo by Daniel Perván*

```
.element {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
}

.clipper {
    position: absolute;
    clip: rect(auto,auto,auto,auto);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.image {
  background: url(http://image.jpg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried doing this but it didn't work. However can you tell me with respect to my code given above,how and where should I change the position :relative or absolute or fixed. I tried but somehow it's not working.

Comment: the disappearing image problem has been solved,thanks! But I still need the effect. Also,the nav bar is off,which is positioned correct when I run it locally.

Comment: It wasn't me who downvoted! I actually upvoted when I checked your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox and Chrome looked the same to me, so not sure what it is that you want to achieve exactly.

If it is the logo's disappearance from the top navbar, I think that has to do with the line-height:50 property.

But I think you want homepage.jpg to be on the background all throughout the page, then you need to move it into body style or you need to create some other div to hold the rest of the page or where you want it to be shown.

You may need to isolate your problem into its own stripped down html version and once you fix it, you may still need to start adding other parts incrementally if there are still other errors when you merge.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` (animate.css line 14). The -webkit- prefix "breaks" the effect in chrome. Actually it creates a new overlaing static image.